# Client-side confirmation on gridview does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project, In gridview i want to add a client-side confirtmation for deleting a record. Everything seems right, browser asks for confirmation, after pressing "yes", nothing happens in gridview as well at database. What's the missing point ? Thanks for answers. Also in gridview, after pressing edit button "ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code" exception occurs

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlSource1" DataKeyNames="id"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" OnRowDataBound="grid1_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" ButtonType="Image" DeleteImageUrl="~/Images/delete.gif" />
                        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" ButtonType="Image" SelectImageUrl="~/Images/select.gif" />
                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ButtonType="Image" EditImageUrl="~/Images/edit.gif" UpdateImageUrl="~/Images/update.png" CancelImageUrl="~/Images/delete.gif" CausesValidation="false" />                        
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Company ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Company Name" />        
                    </Columns>    
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

---

```
protected void grid1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            ImageButton del = (ImageButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
            del.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure to delete ? ');";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the function written for selectedindexchanged.. Also, where is the logic written for deleting the row?

Comment: Firstly, i have handled it without any c# code-behind. Now I want to add some features. I have only written the grid1_RowDataBound function..what else have i to do?

Comment: add selectedindexchanged function. That will handle your deletion/edit part...Refer msdn for selectedindexchanged